# "ALL"-Option for BY (SAS PROC TABULATE)

Tags: excel, sas, proc, tabulate

```
ODS EXCEL FILE="/mypoath/myfile.xlsx" options(
    frozen_headers="3"
    sheet_name="#byval1");
 PROC TABULATE data=out;
  BY byVariable; 
  CLASS varA varB;
  TABLES varA, varB;
 RUN;
ODS EXCEL CLOSE;
```

The code above creates an excel-file with different sheets. There is one sheet for each value of the variable `byVariable`. Is there a way to create an additional sheet "ALL" which contains the results for all values of the `byVariable` together? I mean something like "ALL" (used in the TABLES-section). I tried `BY ALL byVar` already (which doesn't work).
Thanks for help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simple answer is NO.  If you want all of the data then don't use the BY statement.

```
ODS EXCEL FILE="/mypoath/myfile.xlsx" options(frozen_headers="3");
ODS EXCEL options(sheet_name="ALL");
PROC TABULATE data=out;
  CLASS varA varB;
  TABLES varA, varB;
RUN;
ODS EXCEL options(sheet_name="#byval1");
PROC TABULATE data=out;
  BY byVariable; 
  CLASS varA varB;
  TABLES varA, varB;
RUN;
ODS EXCEL CLOSE;
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no such option.

You can:

- rerun the report without `BY`, or
- *stack* the data on itself modifying the by variable to be `ALL` -- such that it is higher than all existant by values.

```
data stacked / view=stacked;
  set 
    have
    have (in=stackflag)
  ;

  if stackflag then do;
    byvar = 'A0'x || 'ALL';        * A0 forces value to be 'after' other original byVar values;
  end
run;

proc tabulate data=stacked;
  by byvar; 
  …
```

Note: `'A0'x` is a hard space ASCII character